# How to combine dask futures in a final step?

Tags: dask

I start a dask client and send it tasks via a loop.

```
tasks = []
for order in orderIDs:
   tasks.append(client.submit(process,allcars.get_group(order),allorders.get_group(order)))
```

when the tasks complete, the list contains pandas DataFrames like this:

```
[<Future: finished, type: pandas.DataFrame, key: process-93e68764db2995b23271abe5d531a5bf>, <Future: finished, type: pandas.DataFrame, key: process-04395a45d14a1ac440363d52379f5e55>]
```

Before dask, I used `pd.concat` to get a final dataframe. This was faster then appending dataframes.

However, `pd.concat(tasks)` complains "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

When I try `dd.from_delayed(tasks)` it complains "AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'from_delayed'"

How can I concat (vertically stack) the contents of this list? Is there any way to make this last step distributed?

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to submit the `pd.concat` function onto the list of tasks.

```
future = client.submit(pd.concat, tasks)
```

Comment: Thanks @mrocklin. I'll try your solution and either select it as the answer or provide a mcve as requested above.